# How can I use a class object's function globally, during its definition?

Tags: python, class

Sorry for the awkwardly phrased title.

Currently, I'm using Tkinter to create a UI for my program. I'm using individual classes for my Tk windows, one as a main menu that's always open and others that open for brief periods of interaction. I was hoping to have other functions interact with my main function by naming it and then calling it by its global name.

Upon testing though, I'd end up with NameErrors. I boiled it down to this example in IDLE:

```
>>> def test():
    mm.do()


>>> class tclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Test text"
        test()
    def do(self):
        print self.text


>>> mm = tclass()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    mm = tclass()
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 4, in __init__
    test()
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 2, in test
    mm.do()
NameError: global name 'mm' is not defined
```

Does anyone have any suggestion to circumventing this problem?

Update, more info: Basically I was trying to have a window's buttons disabled upon opening the new window, then after a certain point in the new window's functions, to call the main menu's function to re-enable its buttons. I'm still actively learning Python as I progress through this project, and hadn't realized my Tkinter tutorials used old code. I haven't had a need for classes up to this point. I will now convert to new style classes.

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example that explains *what* you're trying to achieve and *why* you're approaching it this way? Why don't you pass `self` to `test` explicitly, for example? That way it would work even when you created instances that weren't assigned to `mm`, which seems like an absurdly fragile requirement. And why are you using an old-style class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work. The reason for that is pretty simple:

```
mm = tclass()
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
temp = tclass()
mm = temp
```

I.e., my point is that the *right side* of the assignment is evaluated first. So in your case, the object is created and the initializer runs. The `__init__` calls `test`, and `test` tries to access an object `mm`. It cannot find that in the local namespace, so it goes up to the global namespace, and there is still no `mm`. So it fails.

Assuming it would not fail, only *then* the call `tclass()` returns and the value (the object instance) can be assigned to `mm`, creating that name in the global namespace. So only now, the `test` function could run.

But the problem would be still there if `mm` existed before. Because `test()` called from within `__init__` will *always* access the old value of `mm`, never the newly constructed object.

Instead, you should just not rely on global variables, and just pass the instance to the function:

```
def test(mm): # mm is now a parameter
    mm.do()

class tclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Test text"
        test(self) # pass the current instance to the function
    def do(self):
        print self.text

mm = tclass()
```

Comment: This explanation and example code made the most sense. Thank you for the help. Passing self is also an easy fix that doesn't require a whole logical redesign for me.

Answer (score 0):

This fails because the `mm` variable doesn't exist until after Python has finished constructing and initializing the `tclass` instance (in `mm = tclass()`).  That's not done until `__init__()` returns.  You will need to either pass `self` to the `test()` function explicitly as a parameter, or don't call `test()` from `__init__()`.

You could also rewrite `test()` as a method, which will allow you to pass the `self` parameter automatically.  But that might not work well in other circumstances.  If you need both a method and a function, consider writing something like this:

```
def test():
    return mm.test()

class tclass(object):
    # I suggest using a new-style class unless there's a good reason not to
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Test text"
        self.test()
    def do(self):
        print self.text
    def test(self):
        self.do()

mm = tclass()
```